# How to use UIWebView to display a website in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am using UIWebView to open a link in my app and I submitted it to the AppStore which resulted in the rejection with reason of 2.12 of review guidline which says

> 2.12: Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Is it because I used UIWebView to open a web site.

Comment: What is the difference between your app and Safari opened on your website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIWebView` are used to open the websites. But your application must have certain more features.

The application containing only a `UIWebView` to open a website is of no use as instead you can open the website directly in the Safari and in that open the `Actionsheet` from the bottom bar and tap on **Add to Home Screen** option. It will be same as the application you have tried to upload on Appstore.

Comment: my app contain much more than webview.it displays the schedule detail of the team that the app belong and display the players details, provides live notifications, facebook integration,add events to iphone calender,call etc,etc... still apple rejected it. i used web view only at one place.

Answer (score 3):

It is not because you open a website with UIWebView, but it might be because your app does only that. Your app must do more that just that.

Comment: thanks for answer but my app contain much more than that. i found the apple guidlines unclear an confusing. i'm trying to solve the issues hopfully it accepted this time..thanks again

Answer (score -1):

As far as my knowledge you are not providing any useful information i.e nothing is special in your app